# Solving for a complex function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers

EDIT1:

How is it possible to find/solve for a continuously differentiable function of  a complex variable
$~f[x+iy]~$ if its real and imaginary parts satisfy:

$$x^{\Re[f]} + y^{\Im[f]} =  x^2 + y^2~  $$where $~\Re[f]~:~$ real part of $~z~$ and  $~\Im[f]~:~$ imaginary part of $~z~$?

Are there solutions other than complex constant  $~2+2i~?$

EDIT2:

Stated in other words.. can we solve for two $(u,v)$ components satisfying Cauchy-Riemann conditions when total three equations (two among them partial differential, one algebraic ) are given:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{ \partial x }= \frac{\partial v}{ \partial y },
\frac{\partial u}{ \partial y }= -\frac{\partial v}{ \partial x } $$

$$x^u + y^v =  x^2 + y^2? $$

What arbitrary functions can form a solution or part of it?

EDIT3:

Before being migrated from *Mathematica*, one response that produced a voluminous output but needed caution about relevance is:

```
FindInstance[x^rez + y^imz == x^2 + y^2, {rez, imz, x, y}, Reals, 20]
```

Comment: If re{z}=2 and if im{z}=0 then you have solution?

Comment: Are there any other (non-obvious) function solutions? Please allow me to slightly change the question.. to include y in rhs .. hope is in order.

Comment: Your question is unclearly formulated. are $x=\Re z$ and $y=\Im z$? How does it deal with Mathematica? Isn't MSE a right forum for such questions?

Comment: This asks whether there can be real values `{c,d}` such that the sum `x^c+y^d` is always (that is, for all `{x,y}`) equal to the bivariate polynomial `x^2+y^2`. The answer is no, there are no other solutions.

Comment: And of course this is a question about the underlying math, hence really belongs on a different forum such as math.SE.

Comment: This question is not clear.  What, if anything, is the connection between $z$ and $x,y$?  For instance, with $(x,y)=(2,3)$ the right hand is $2^2+3^2=13$.  Thus if we take $z=\log_2 {12} + i\times 0$ we get a solution.  Or $z=\log_2 {10}+i\log_3 3$.  Are these the sort of solutions you are hoping for?

Comment: It's extremely unclear: You ask how to find $f$ satisfying a certain condition, but there's no "$f$"  in the statement of that condition! (Maybe you meant $\Re f$ and $\Im f$ in place of $\Re z$ and $\Im z$???)

Comment: Thanks. edited that edit.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{u(x,y)}+y^{v(x,y)}=x^2+y^2$$ has innumerable solutions.

Choose $v(x,y)$ arbitrarily, and

$$u(x,y)=\log_x(x^2+y^2-y^{v(x,y)}).$$

---

Computing the partial derivatives

$$ux^{u-1}+\log x\,x^u\,u_x+\log y\,y^v\,v_x=2x$$

$$uy^{u-1}+\log x\,x^u\,u_y+\log y\,y^v\,v_y=2y$$

and applying Cauchy-Riemann,

$$\log x\,x^u\,u_x-\log y\,y^v\,u_y=2x-ux^{u-1}$$

$$\log y\,y^v\,u_x+\log x\,x^u\,u_y=2y-uy^{u-1}.$$

So we can get $u_x,u_y$. Not sure this leads us anywhere...

Comment: Does it satisfy Cauchy-Riemann relations?

Comment: @Narasimham: is this required ?

Comment: Yes, Please suggest if I need to improve the question.

Comment: @Narasimham: yes, the fact that the equation includes $\Re$ and $\Im$ is a little misleading.

Comment: OK, some edits came in, hope EDIT2 is now a tad bit  better.

Comment: @Narasimham: saying "differentiable" would have been enough ;-)

Comment: added that,. let's see if it makes a difference.